# Where do I put configuration files for testing?

Tags: 8, configuration, testing

Hopefully, this will be a simple question.

I am writing a kernel test for a class, called FooConfig, that reads from a configuration file. For the purpose of facilitating this test, I need a configuration YAML file that exists purely for testing.

So the question is: is it best practice for this configuration file to live under `config/install`, or should it exist within the `/tests` directory?

Comment: One way is to create a small `testing module` that contains specific config you need for a test, then have the test use it as a dependency. In my case, I put that module itself under the `tests` directory and marked it as hidden in its info file.

Comment: Now why didn't I think of that. :) This is technically the answer, so if you would like to post this as an answer, I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to create a small testing module that contains specific config you need for a test, then have the test use it as a dependency. In my case, I put that module itself under the tests directory and marked it as hidden in its info file.

Although a drawback would be keeping these config files up to date when the system changes - but failing tests should point you in that direction too.

For Kernel tests be sure to call and install the test modules config.